# When Russell refers to "the morality of slaves" in In Praise of Idleness is he referencing Nietzsche?

Tags: nietzsche, bertrand-russell

In Praise of Idleness features the line "The morality of work is the morality of slaves, and the modern world has no need of slavery." It also later references "the morality of the Slave State". Is Russell referring to Nietzche's Slave Morality here, or some other concept?

Comment: Russell is referring to a historical fact. Nietzsche did it more rhetorically before him, but there is no need to suppose that Russell somehow alludes to Nietzsche.

Comment: Can you provide page cites to Russell?

Comment: @MarkAndrews this is the version I read https://harpers.org/archive/1932/10/in-praise-of-idleness/ - CTRL-F "morality" finds the two quotes (and nothing else)